# Government Shutdown - application deadlines for fellowships and grants

Tags: funding, united-states, special-issue, government-institutes

Will application deadlines for federally-funded fellowships and grants be extended, due to the ongoing government shutdown here in the States?  Is there even anyone to contact (and get a response from) at this time, regarding application deadlines?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[NDSEG](https://www.ndsegfellowships.org/) deadline for 2019 is already over.  It looks like their 2020 deadline is unchanged.  Their funding may not be impacted (I can't keep track of which agencies are shutdown and which aren't).  I know [EIA](https://www.eia.gov/) is still funded so I imaging all of [DOE](https://www.energy.gov/) is.  But I really don't know for sure.  In any case, I would just treat it as same deadline.

When I did stuff like this you had to actually mail off for paper applications.  But I imagine this stuff is all on the net.   So really nothing stopping you from doing applications.

Comment: Why do you believe that the question is about NDSEG deadlines? And what does that acronym stands for? The same goes for EIA and DOE.

Comment: I was just adding that.  Earlier person had noted NSF.  NDSEG is probably the Pepsi to NSF's Coke in terms of numbers.

Comment: It's not that hard to look up which agencies are affected or not before writing an answer... DOE and DOD are indeed unaffected, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_federal_government_shutdown_of_2018%E2%80%932019).

Comment: They are common abbreviations in US agency science discussions.  If you don't know them, GIYF.  Don't get bent about this being US specific, since this is a discussion of OUR shutdown.  Now the yellow vest thing or Brexit.  That's someone else's problem.  But this is ours.  ;-)

Comment: Nice add, Anyon.  (Of course you could make the same point about question askers.)

Comment: "DOE" is potentially ambiguous: Energy or Education?

Comment: Not in context:  "I know EIA is still funded so I imaging [sic] all of DOE is."

Comment: Ok.  I added some links which may be helpful.

Comment: @guest This is unrelated to your answer, but are [this account](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/103024/guest) and [this account](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/102739/guest) also you?

Comment: @NateEldredge DOE is always Energy. Education is ED. And DOT is Transportation, Treasury is TREAS. As mentioned, it's standard lingo in the field.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation should be moved to chat. If you're reading this and feel the need to add your two cents, please go post it in that chat room.

Answer (score 6):

## For the National Science Foundation (NSF)

If your grant or fellowship is funded by the NSF, then the deadline remains the same.

From the NSF page, https://www.nsf.gov/shutdown/grantees.jsp, *Information About the Government Shutdown for NSF Proposers and Grantees*:

> **Impact on Existing Deadlines**
>
> During a lapse in appropriations, NSF will continue to accept proposal
>   submissions pursuant to existing deadlines.

You should read this as "they will accept your proposal, will not process it, and the dead-line remains unchanged" during the shutdown.

You will not get any answer to your email during the shutdown.
Quoting the same page:

> Responses to any inquiries received regarding upcoming deadlines, including proposal preparation, will be deferred until normal operations resume.

---

### Update

https://www.nsf.gov/ says:

> With the enactment of continuing appropriations through February 15, 2019, NSF is working to resume operations. Employees should report to work on their next scheduled work day.  For most staff, that will be Monday, January 28, 2019. NSF headquarters will be open to all staff starting at 6:00 a.m. Monday, January 28, 2019.